# What is the difference between closed-form expression and closed-form function?

Tags: definition, closed-form

What is the difference, if any, between a closed-form expression and a closed-form function? I have seen those terms used interchangeably, but is there any difference between them, and if so, what is the difference?

Comment: Well, the closed form expression for, say, $\sum \frac 1{2^n}$ is $2$, which I would not consider a function.  For example.  However $\frac 1{1-x}$ is a closed form function equal to $\sum x^n$.  (for suitable $x$).

Answer (score 0):

A [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) is a [mathematical expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(mathematics)) (in closed form). A closed-form function is a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) (with a function expression that is a closed-form expression).